# Google Sheets Script to Auto Send Email when New Row Added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to scripts and not very familiar with code so I think this issue has to do with the StartRow and LastRow, but I'm not sure how to edit it to work as intended, pulling data from only one row at a time.

I have the below script, which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421907/send-email-for-new-row-added-using-google-script). The script sends an email when Column H = "Y" and I <> "Y".

The issue I'm experiencing is I want an email sent to notify me of each new user (1 new user = 1 new row) is added to the sheet, but many times multiple users/rows are added at one time, since they're added through a data connector, connecting Salesforce data to the sheet and the data connector refreshes the database every 24 hours.

Each individual email should contain Request, Account, Appointment, and User information from each individual row - **this is what I want for each new row**:

```
Request: TEST

Account: TEST

Appointment Created Date: Thu Oct 06 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

User: TEST
```

However, since there are multiple new rows being added at a time, the first row's email will look good but the email for the 2nd row will have BOTH its own row information and the first row's - **this is what I DO NOT want, but currently get**:

```
Request: TEST

Account: TEST

Appointment Created Date: Fri Oct 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

User: TEST

Request: TEST

Account: TEST

Appointment Created Date: Thu Oct 06 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

User: TEST
```

The 3rd row's email will have information of all 3 rows in the body of the email. **How do I limit each email to only contain the information relevant to the individual row?**

Thanks in advance!

```
       function email()  
       {
    
      //setup function   
      var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("First Time Users");     
      var StartRow = 2; //first row of data to process   
      var LastRow = ActiveSheet.getLastRow();   
      var RowRange = LastRow - StartRow + 1;   
      var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,9);   
      var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();   
      var message = "" 
      for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) 
       
        {
          var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
          var EmailSent = CurrentRow[8]; 
          if (CurrentRow[7] == "Y" && EmailSent!= "Y") 
          {
            message +=                      //set HTML template for information
              "<p><b>Request: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Account: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Appointment Created Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +  
              "<p><b>User: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>"; 
            var setRow = i + StartRow;
            var SendTo = "testemail@gmail.com";
            var Subject = "First Time User Submitted Ask:  " + CurrentRow[1];    //set subject line   
            //send the actual email  
               MailApp.sendEmail
                      ({
                            to: SendTo,
                            cc: "",
                            subject: Subject,
                            htmlBody: message,
                      });
      
             ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 9).setValue("Y");  //update the row if email is sent
          }     
      } 
  }
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you provide a sample output of your expected results, or any edits that you have made for the provided script.

Comment: I added sample expected results and current results. The edits from the original script can be seen in the script I provided above (versus the script in the other linked question I referenced for this script) - I mainly just edited the number of columns it's looking at and the body of the email.

Comment: So here's the thing, since you have stated that you are using a Google Sheets Add-on which is a Salesforce Data Connector where it populates salesforce reports unto Google Sheets, what happens is that everytime this specific add-on is ran, it deletes the content of the specific sheet, and replaces it with new values from the salesforce report that it is references from.

Comment: So for us to make this possible to populate only new data from the salesforce report, you might need to separate it into 2 sheets. One, which is the data from the salesforce report connected through the data connector add-on, and second is the data that you would want the script to run, in this way, we can compare if a user is already existing based from the sheet where the script is getting the data, and add only new users from the data connector sheet

Comment: Also can you provide a sample sheet with dummy values for testing purposes? Just to set your expectation that your personal email address will be visible as well to this post so I would understand if it is not possible for you to provide a sample sheet, but it will definitely be helpful for us to replicate your script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `var message = ""` is declared the outside of the loop. And, the value is added using `message +=`. In this case, the value of `message` is grown every loop. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.
- When `setValue` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function email() {
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("First Time Users");
  var StartRow = 2;
  var LastRow = ActiveSheet.getLastRow();
  var RowRange = LastRow - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow, 1, RowRange, 9);
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  var ranges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < AllValues.length; i++) {
    var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[8];
    if (CurrentRow[7] == "Y" && EmailSent != "Y") {
      var message =
        "<p><b>Request: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Account: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Appointment Created Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>User: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>";
      var setRow = i + StartRow;
      var SendTo = "testemail@gmail.com";
      var Subject = "First Time User Submitted Ask:  " + CurrentRow[1];
      MailApp.sendEmail
        ({
          to: SendTo,
          cc: "",
          subject: Subject,
          htmlBody: message,
        });
      ranges.push("I" + setRow);
    }
  }
  ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y");
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: @allison Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi @tanaike I added an on change trigger and it ran once but I’m now getting an error: Exception: Ranges must have at least one range. Any idea why/how to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: @allison About `I added an on change trigger and it ran once but I’m now getting an error: Exception: Ranges must have at least one range. Any idea why/how to resolve this?`, I would like to support you. But your new question is different from your this question. So, can you post it as a new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?