# Google Apps Script Email Automation Errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993146/google-sheets-script-to-auto-send-email-when-new-row-added/73993904?noredirect=1#comment130663528_73993904) and was able to have emails auto-send using the modified script shared with me in the answer...however I'm running into a couple of issues.

The Google Sheet has one tab with data imported via a Google Sheets add-on called Data Connector. It auto-refreshes data connected from Salesforce, to Sheets, every 24 hours. In the "First Time Users" tab I'm using a query to pull all new users from the imported data tab and running the script off of this tab. Newest users are always added to the top of the sheet, so rows of data which the script has already sent an email based on, will move down as new data is added to the top of the sheet.

I want this script to run anytime the sheet changes (this will typically happen when the imported data refreshes) and I want an email to be sent out to a specific email address, if there's a new user (one email per new user and multiple new users may be added at one time).

This is the script I got from my last posted question:

```
  function email() {
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("First Time Users");
  var StartRow = 2;
  var LastRow = ActiveSheet.getLastRow();
  var RowRange = LastRow - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow, 1, RowRange, 9);
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  var ranges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < AllValues.length; i++) {
    var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[8];
    if (CurrentRow[7] == "Y" && EmailSent != "Y") {
      var message =
        "<p><b>Request: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Account: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Appointment Created Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>User: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>";
      var setRow = i + StartRow;
      var SendTo = "testemail@gmail.com";
      var Subject = "First Time User Submitted Ask:  " + CurrentRow[1];
      MailApp.sendEmail
        ({
          to: SendTo,
          cc: "",
          subject: Subject,
          htmlBody: message,
        });
      ranges.push("I" + setRow);
    }
  }
  ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y");
}
```

I added the following trigger, hoping it would execute the script every time new users are added to the "First Time Users" tab:
[image]

My issues are the following:

1. Trigger/execution error: *Exception: Ranges must have at least one range.
   at email(Code:103:15)*
2. The email notification contains information from the last row of the sheet, moving up, rather than the row with the new user which is the row(s) where there's no "Y" under the "Sent" column, Column I. The "Y" is added to this column once the script executes and sends out an email. (Ex., if I receive 3 notification emails for 3 new users, the data in the email has data from the last row, the next email has data from the second to last row, and the third email has data from the third to last row in the sheet).

[Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WcN3gxv_EE3e1YZLwUUXmCSgszHrCdQMWdLmD9P4I0/edit?usp=sharing) of what the "First Time Users" tab looks like. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the script and it's working flawlessly, I used a `Time-Driven` trigger instead of an `OnChange` trigger, in your situation as you mentioned that the Salesforce connector is refreshing data every 24 hours it's best for you to have the trigger run every couple of minutes.

[image]

You may want to try using it as a Time driven trigger instead. This is how the latest test emails were received:

[image]

This is how the emails were received in my mailbox:

[image]

This is how the execution is displayed in the logs:

[image]

As you may notice there are no errors shown in the logs so I would recommend using Time-driven triggers instead.

Comment: Thank you! That was all I had to do was choose a different trigger. Seems to work now. Appreciate it!

Comment: Ahh! Actually, I started getting some trigger errors again, the same one. I see a few new rows were added to the sheet, Column I says "Y" that the emails were sent (this was changed by the script) but I didn't receive any emails. The error says: Exception: Ranges must have at least one range. Any idea how to fix this?