# Google Sheets Script Error: Exception: Ranges must have at least one range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019400/google-apps-script-email-automation-errors/74020391#74020391) and thought I had gotten the resolution, however, after it ran properly the first time, the next day I ended up with a bunch of trigger errors stating: *Exception: Ranges must have at least one range.*

The new rows of data being added are still being marked "Y" in Column I, as if the email got sent out for it, but I'm either not receiving an email, only receiving one email when more than one row was added at one time, or receiving an email containing information from the wrong row of data (the last/oldest row rather than the new row).

This is the script I'm using to send an email notification whenever new row(s) of data are added - it should be sending one email per new row of data, and then mark "Y" in Column I of the corresponding row.

```
  function email() {
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("First Time Users");
  var StartRow = 2;
  var LastRow = ActiveSheet.getLastRow();
  var RowRange = LastRow - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow, 1, RowRange, 9);
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  var ranges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < AllValues.length; i++) {
    var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[8];
    if (CurrentRow[7] == "Y" && EmailSent != "Y") {
      var message =
        "<p><b>Request: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Account: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Appointment Created Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>User: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>";
      var setRow = i + StartRow;
      var SendTo = "testemail@gmail.com";
      var Subject = "First Time User Submitted Ask:  " + CurrentRow[1];
      MailApp.sendEmail
        ({
          to: SendTo,
          cc: "",
          subject: Subject,
          htmlBody: message,
        });
      ranges.push("I" + setRow);
    }
  }
  ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y");
}
```

This is the trigger I have which is currently set to run every 24 hours...previously I had it run every 5 minutes (before this, I had used an On Change trigger, as shown in my previous question linked above):

[image]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code you are running the `ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y");` every time, so it will still run even if all range from column I is filled with Y which is why the **ranges** array is empty.

From the logic you've stated

> it should be sending one email per new row of data, and then mark "Y"
> in Column I of the corresponding row.

I think it makes more sense if you put the line           `ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y");` inside the condition `if (CurrentRow[7] == "Y" && EmailSent != "Y")` after the `MailApp.sendEmail`. Since you are only setting the value "Y" in column I if EmailSent (which is also column I) is not Y and after sending the email.

See final code below:

```
  function email() {
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("First Time Users");
  var StartRow = 2;
  var LastRow = ActiveSheet.getLastRow();
  var RowRange = LastRow - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow, 1, RowRange, 9);
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  var ranges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < AllValues.length; i++) {
    var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
    var EmailSent = CurrentRow[8];
    if (CurrentRow[7] == "Y" && EmailSent != "Y") {
      var message =
        "<p><b>Request: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Account: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Appointment Created Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>User: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>";
      var setRow = i + StartRow;
      var SendTo = "da@devopstraining.club";
      var Subject = "First Time User Submitted Ask:  " + CurrentRow[1];
      MailApp.sendEmail
        ({
          to: SendTo,
          cc: "",
          subject: Subject,
          htmlBody: message,
        });
      ranges.push("I" + setRow);
      ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y"); //moved inside the condition
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this updated script which has solved the trigger error issue, however, I'm still getting notified of new Users incorrectly - instead of containing the information from the newly added rows, it sends me information of the bottom rows. So if there are 5 new rows of new user data added to the top of the sheet, I get emails containing information of the 5 bottom, oldest rows...any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @allison Thank you for your reply. How are the new users being added? I have tested this script multiple times and it works correctly. It should only email those with "Y" in Column H (Ready to Email) and blank in Column I (Sent?). And those marked with "Y" will be ignored. It is not being based on either the last or current row.

Comment: I have one tab on the sheet with data auto-imported every 24 hours by a Google Sheets Add-On called Data Connector (data is connected from Salesforce). The tab I mocked up that I have the script look at has a Query formula pulling in new users from the data tab, newest on top. It seems when I delete the "Y" in Column I, I get the right email sent to me but when the data auto-updates, I always get the old user information sent to me through the script...typing this out makes me think maybe I need to Query the data with newest users on the bottom. I'll try that!

Comment: @allison yes it is supposed to only email those blanks in Column I. Unless the data being populated from the salesforce is already marked Y in column I, it will not be emailed. Let me know how this goes, I'm also curious.

Comment: I had to reverse the order of the data in the new user data tab so the newest users are on the bottom. Because the query was pulling new users to the top and moving the older users down, the "Y" in Col H and I were not moving with them since the query didn't touch those two columns. Now, with the new users at the bottom of the sheet, Col H and I are still blank so it emails the correct user information instead of emailing the oldest user information. This was totally on me - your script edit was the solution to the trigger errors I was having. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().forEach(r => r.setValue("Y"));
```

or this:

```
function email() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("First Time Users");
  var sr = 2;
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();
  var numrows = lr - sr + 1;
  var rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, numrows, 9);
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var ranges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var r = vs[i];
    if (r[7] == "Y" && r[8] != "Y") {
      var message =
        "<p><b>Request: </b>" + r[0] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Account: </b>" + r[1] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Appointment Created Date: </b>" + r[4] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>User: </b>" + r[5] + "</p>";
      var setRow = i + sr;
      var SendTo = "testemail@gmail.com";
      var Subject = "First Time User Submitted Ask:  " + r[1];
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message});
      sh.getRange(setRow,9).setValue("Y")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message of `Exception: Ranges must have at least one range.`, I guessed that in your script, an array of `ranges` is empty. When `ranges` is an empty array, such an error occurs. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y");
```

#### To:

```
if (ranges.length == 0) return;
ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y");
```

- By this, when `ranges` is empty array, `ActiveSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Y")` is not run. Your current error can be avoided.